# How to calculate angle of two vectors for determining vertex concavity in ear clipping algorithm

Tags: c++, polygon, c++20, computational-geometry, triangulation

I am trying to implement this ear clipping algorithm (from the pseudocode) [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1212/1212.6038.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20ear%20clipping%20triangulation%20algorithm,newly%20formed%20triangle%20is%20valid.) Currently at the point in the algorithm where I am trying to calculate the angle of each vertex in a polygon.  I also got the idea of how to calculate the angles with vectors here: [here](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/triangulating-polygons-using-the-ear-clipping-algorithm/1875449) This way I can also determine convexity/concavity. Also my vertices are in counter clockwise order.

This is a helper function I wrote to help in calculating the angle of each vertex:

```
void calcConvexity(Node&* prev, Node&* curr, Node&* next) {
    glm::vec2 u(0.0f), v(0.0f);
    u.x = curr->x - prev->x;
    u.y = curr->y - prev->y;
    v.x = curr->x - next->x;
    v.y = curr->y - next->y;
        
        // Calculating angle (in radians)
    curr->Angle =
        ((u.x * v.y) - (u.y * v.x))        
        /
        std::sqrt((std::pow(u.x, 2.0f) + std::pow(u.y, 2.0f)) * 
                std::sqrt(std::pow(v.x, 2.0f) + std::pow(v.y, 2.0f));

        // Convert to degrees
    curr->Angle = (180 / 3.141592653589793238463) * curr->Angle;

    if (curr->Angle < 180.0f)
        curr->isConvex = true; // The vertex is convex
    else
        curr->isConvex = false;
}
```

I was expecting most of the angles to come out between 0 and 360 but they did not. I am not sure what further calculations or corrections I need to make. Also, in the node class I have a boolean attribute called isConvex. I know something wrong is happening because every vertex is having there isConvex attribute set to true even when there degree is greater than 180.0f (in the example below).

Here is an actual example output as well:
(The blue arrows are suppose to be facing in towards the nodes I just cant update the picture on here)
[Polygon With vectors to each vertice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szsil.png)
as well as the isConvex values for each node:
[Node isConvex Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iea0X.png)
and the angles:
[Node angle values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PkzH.png)

I have tried facing the vectors in different directions as well as using the GLM library for vector operations.

I apologize if any of what I have supplied is confusing, this is my first time messing with computational geometry in general. So I am just wondering what am I doing wrong in my calcConvexity method?

UPDATED CODE:

```
void calcConvexity(Node&* prev, Node&* curr, Node&* next) {
    glm::vec2 u(0.0f), v(0.0f);
    u.x = curr->x - prev->x;
    u.y = curr->y - prev->y;
    v.x = curr->x - next->x;
    v.y = curr->y - next->y;

    float CrossProduct = ((u.x * v.y) - (u.y * v.x));
    
    if (CrossProduct < 0)
        curr->isConvex = true; // The vertex is convex
    else
        curr->isConvex = false; // Otherwise concave
     
    curr->Angle =
        (CrossProduct)        
        /
        std::sqrt((std::pow(u.x, 2.0f) + std::pow(u.y, 2.0f)) * 
                std::sqrt(std::pow(v.x, 2.0f) + std::pow(v.y, 2.0f));

    curr->Angle = glm::degrees(std::asin(curr->Angle));
}
```

So the solution I came up with is this:
I use the Cross product to determine convexity and then I use a slightly different angle formula: cos(curr->Angle) = (u.b) / (|u||v|)
My main problem was the the formula with sin was outputting between -90 and 90 while the formula with cos outputs between 0 and 180
Code that works:

```
void Graph::calcConvexity(Node*& prev, Node*& curr, Node*& next) {
    glm::vec2 u(0.0f), v(0.0f);
    u.x = curr->x - prev->x;
    u.y = curr->y - prev->y;
    v.x = curr->x - next->x;
    v.y = curr->y - next->y;

    float CrossProduct = ((u.x * v.y) - (u.y * v.x));

    if (CrossProduct < 0)
        curr->isConvex = true; // The vertex is convex
    else
        curr->isConvex = false; // Otherwise concave

    float dotProduct = (u.x * v.x) + (u.y * v.y);

    curr->Angle =
        std::acos(dotProduct /
                (std::sqrt(std::pow(u.x, 2.0f) + std::pow(u.y, 2.0f)) *
                std::sqrt(std::pow(v.x, 2.0f) + std::pow(v.y, 2.0f))));

    curr->Angle = glm::degrees(curr->Angle);
}
```

Comment: I'm just looking at this quickly so may be wrong but are you sure you don't want to subtract `curr` from `prev`/`next` rather than subtracting `prev`/`next` from `curr`? The former will give you the vector relative to `curr` being the origin, the latter gives you the vector relative to prev/next.

Comment: @jwezorek yes, that would be more straightforward but by flipping both vectors the angle doesn't change

Comment: You are not computing an angle, but the sine of an angle. Your conversion to degrees does not make sense for two reasons: 1) a sine is not in radians, only the argument is, 2) the comparison can be made directly in radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curr->Angle` appears to be set to `sin(Angle)` from `u` to `v`. Therefore concavity/convexity is determined by the sign of `((u.x * v.y) - (u.y * v.x))`, since the denominator is always positive.

In particular, if the interior of the polygon is on the right as traversing the  vector `u` from its tail to its head, the positive sign of `((u.x * v.y) - (u.y * v.x))` corresponds to a convex angle.

Comment: Thank you your answer has helped my understanding in determining concavity and interior angles. However, when I calculate an interior angle it is only in between 0 - 90 degrees even angles that are obviously greater than that (doesn't matter if its concave or not). I think I am forgetting some trigonometry here because I am not sure if I have to add 2pi but I have tried and most of the time the angles are still incorrect. 
I have updated code above. (also my vertices are counter clockwise)

Comment: I would expect that the angle  `curr->Angle` would be in the range `0` to `pi` since it is computed as `arccos`.  Then in the updated version, you probably want to change the sign of `curr->Angle` based on the sign of the cross product `CrossProduct`, that is, `curr->Angle` should be changed to   `-curr->Angle` (or `2pi-curr->Angle` if you want to end up in the interval from `0` to `2pi`) if `CrossProduct<0` and leave it as is otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to obtain angles is by means of the function `atan2`, which returns a value on four quadrants (usually in `(-π, π]`).

Using the complex number notation, the angle formed by the vectors u to v is given by the argument of u*v where * denotes conjugation.

Anyway, I guess that to determine the concavity/convexity for triangulation, it is enough to consider the signed area of the triangles (cross product of two sides) rather than angles. That tells you if a triangle is clockwise or not.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution will be to calculate cross product between to edges of the corner and look at it sign.
For example we wish to know where to turn corner at p1 then we must calculate:

a = p1 - p0
b = p2 - p1

Find a cross product

cross = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x

if cross == 0 then no turn // 180 degrees

if cross < 0 then turn clockwise

if cross > 0 then turn counter clockwise

Keep in mind that order of polygon points is important.
Depending on they are going in clockwise or counter clockwise the rule can be inverted.